# How to get a readable email from AWS S3 after it's stored there as an object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I've set up SES to receive emails on my domain and then store the emails to S3. I trigger an SNS notification when a new email has arrived which triggers a lambda to do processing with the contents inside the email. Everything works as expected however, I'm not able to get any sensible data out of the emails I fetch from S3. For instance, getting an object from S3 of the email gives me this data :

```
 <div dir=3D"ltr">ssadsadasdasdas</div><br><div class=3D"gmail_quote"><div d=
ir=3D"ltr" class=3D"gmail_attr">On Tue, Nov 5, 2019 at 5:30 PM Rahul Patil =
&lt;<a href=3D"mailto:rahul.patil@name.com">rahul.patil@name.com<=
/a>&gt; wrote:<br></div><blockquote class=3D"gmail_quote" style=3D"margin:0=
px 0px 0px 0.8ex;border-left:1px solid rgb(204,204,204);padding-left:1ex"><=
div dir=3D"ltr">asdsadasdasdasd</div><br><div class=3D"gmail_quote"><div di=
r=3D"ltr" class=3D"gmail_attr">On Tue, Nov 5, 2019 at 5:27 PM &lt;<a href=
=3D"mailto:rahul@name.com" target=3D"_blank">rahul@name.com</a>&g=
t; wrote:<br></div><blockquote class=3D"gmail_quote" style=3D"margin:0px 0p=
x 0px 0.8ex;border-left:1px solid rgb(204,204,204);padding-left:1ex">Body<b=
r>
```

The code which fetches the data

```
const obj = await s3.getObject(getObjectParams).promise();
      console.log(obj);
      let objectData = obj.Body.toString("utf-8");
      console.log(objectData)
```

I don't need all that HTML, just the sender's email and the body would be sufficient. Is there an inbuilt way I can filter the required data? Any node-email-parser modules that can be plugged inside the lamba? More importantly, Am I doing it the right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a parser.

Amazon SES will store incoming emails in S3 in [RFC822](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/) format, meaning *exactly* as they are received from the wire. This is by definition plain text, no matter how complex the email, even if it has attachments. Somewhere inside that RFC822 text piece there may or may not be some HTML in the body. An email's body can be plain text only, it can be HTML (most common) or it can be both.

You'll need to use a library which can parse RFC822. There are quite many of those. Which one to use will depend on your language choice. You'll also need to familiarize yourself with the anatomy of an Internet email message, i.e. RFC822. You'll find a wealth of information on that with a bit of googling. Suggestion: Your own email client can most likely save an email in RFC822 format and then you can use that as an example of what an email truly looks like in its 'native' format. Just have a look at it in your favorite text viewer.

Your question can be rephrased into an RFC822 parsing question. Some people refer to such files as `.eml` files. Same thing.

Happy hunting.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer mate. That certainly helped! I couldn't find an RFC822 compatible parser for node which works 100% accurately all of the time so had to use custom regex for getting the data I wanted from that email Blob.

Comment: You are welcome. If you like the answer, then pls accept it. Btw: I wouldn't personally feel confident with regex'ing my way through an RFC822 document, but if you know what type of emails you receive then it may work. ... most of the time.  :-)

Comment: @peterh Just wanted to ask if you put a bounty on a question in `amazon-web-services`?